# Detect current route with regex, Angular 5

Tags: regex, angular5, angular-router

I'm working on project where I need to know what the route is, and listen for route changes to check what is the current route.

Depending on the route I show some elements (or not) on the UI. There are some routes with IDs.
For example, the next route has IDs in two parts of the route:
`/insights/accounts/113603894122287361289/locations/4211764274983026860`. With a file that contains an object with my whole routes, I set a property which is the **regex** to compare with the current route.

```
LOCATION_INSIGHTS: {
    id: 'LOCATION_INSIGHTS',
    route: '/insights/accounts/:accountId/locations/:locationId',
    regex: /\/insights\/accounts\/\d+\/locations\/\d+$/g,
}
```

So, I do something like this:

```
LOCATION_INSIGHTS.regex.test('/insights/accounts/113603894122287361289/locations/4211764274983026860')
```

Which returns me **True**

Now, the interesting thing comes when I try to get into, for example, the above route. The first time that the page loads, it loads completely fine, and my route matches with my file, so I know where am I, but, when on the same page I change of IDs on the same route, my event listener for route changes detects the change and try to match the route, but it looks like the route does not match with anything and because of that, the UI components are not loaded.

To detect the route changes, on my parent component, I set the next code:

**Imports**

```
import {NavigationStart, Router, NavigationEnd, Event, NavigationError} from '@angular/router';
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor(
    private router: Router
) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {

        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            console.log('NAVIGATION START', event);
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.currentRoute = event.urlAfterRedirects;
            this.matchRoute();
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
            console.log('NAVIGATION ERROR', event);
        }
    });
}
```

**matchRoute() Function**

```
private matchRoute() {
    this.matchedRoute = this.regexRoutesArray.find((route: any) => route.regex.test(this.currentRoute));
}
```

**regexRoutesArray**

```
ACCOUNTS: {
    id: 'ACCOUNTS',
    route: '/setup/accounts',
    regex: /\/setup\/accounts$/g
},
LOCATIONS: {
    id: 'LOCATIONS',
    route: '/setup/accounts/:accountId/locations',
    regex: /\/setup\/accounts\/\d+\/locations$/g
},
LOCATION_INSIGHTS: {
    id: 'LOCATION_INSIGHTS',
    route: '/insights/accounts/:accountId/locations/:locationId',
    regex: /\/insights\/accounts\/\d+\/locations\/\d+$/g
},
LOCATION_KEYWORD: {
    id: 'LOCATION_KEYWORD',
    route: '/keyword-report/accounts/:accountId/locations/:locationId',
    regex: /\/keyword-report\/accounts\/\d+\/locations\/\d+$/g
},
LOCATION_REVIEWS: {
    id: 'LOCATION_REVIEWS',
    route: '/insights/accounts/:accountId/locations/:locationId/reviews',
    regex: /\/insights\/accounts\/\d+\/locations\/\d+\/reviews$/g
},
REPORTS: {
    id: 'REPORTS',
    route: '/reports',
    regex: /\/reports$/g
},
REPORT_REVIEW: {
    id: 'REPORT_REVIEW',
    route: '/reports/:hash/reviews',
    regex: /\/reports\/(0x|0X)?[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\/reviews$/g
},
REPORT_COMPARISON: {
    id: 'REPORT_COMPARISON',
    route: '/reports/:hash/comparison',
    regex: /\/reports\/(0x|0X)?[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\/comparison/g
},
REPORT_INSIGHT: {
    id: 'REPORT_INSIGHT',
    route: '/reports/:hash',
    regex: /\/reports\/(0x|0X)?[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$/g
},
SETTINGS: {
    id: 'SETTINGS',
    route: '/settings',
    regex: /\/settings$/g
},
PROFILE: {
    id: 'PROFILE',
    route: '/profile',
    regex: /\/profile$/g
},
USER_LOCATIONS: {
    id: 'USER_LOCATIONS',
    route: '/locations',
    regex: /\/locations$/g
}
```

Any suggestions on how to use the **Router Event Obvservable**, is there something that I'm not doing, or, the maybe the *regex* are not good enough.

Comment: Why are you using the _global_ flag `//g` ?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using the `$` anchor ?

Comment: `(0x|0X)` ~ `(0[xX])`